# Tracking redirects without analytics software

Tags: php

I am running a comparison platform which redirects to other, third-party websites. I want to track those redirects – only the amount of clicks, nothing like IP address etc.

For now I am using Matomo for this case. The problem: Due to the data protection laws it requires user consent, so tracking is not 100% accurate.

My idea was to write a simple tracking script by myself in PHP which just counts every redirect and put it in an SQL table every time the redirect page is loaded:

```
UPDATE redirects
SET redirect_count = redirect_count + 1
```

The problem: This will, I think, also track search robots etc. So it is not accurate again.

Any hints for a beginner how to write a little accurate click-tracking script?

Or is there any script out on the market that fit to my needs?

Thank you!

Comment: _This will, I think, also track search robots etc.._ No this query will just increment the value of column `redirect_count `. It is the logic within php which determines what is a "redirect"

Comment: Most, if not all, search engine robots clearly identify themselves via user-agent. You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to exclude running your logic when your PHP script is executed.